# How to make createObjectUrl() work with react-router?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

`window.createObjectUrl()` creates an URL with the shape of `blob:http://domain/generatedString`, I am trying to use this URI inside an `<iframe>` but it does not seem to work because `react-router` redirects me to the homepage if none of the rules match because it has a switch like so:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route exact  path="/a" component={A} />
  <Route exact  path="/b" component={B} />
  <Route component={nomatch} />
</Switch>
```

How do I make a rule for one of these blob URIs?

**Edit**: Ok the answer was not react-router, it was something else messing up my blob. Sadly, I do not remember what it was. But hey, now you know it is not react-router :+)

Answer (score 6):

When you open the link in your browser, don't forget `blob:` in front of your URL.

Dont try: 
`http://domain/generatedString`

But 
`blob:http://domain/generatedString`

So your react app will not be called so does the `react router`

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like this in JSX:

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(someData)
const downloadLink = React.createElement('a', { download: 'filename.csv', href: url}, 'download')

return (downloadLink)
```